# Is Yahoo OpenID login broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, yahoo

Have just tried to login as usual with Yahoo open id (clicking that yahoo button on other login options screen).

And I'm getting:

> No OpenId endpoint found

This is on SE side.

Tried manually entering URLs:

- https://yahoo.com
- https://openid.yahoo.com

The one that worked was:

- https://me.yahoo.com/

How strange.

Is it some kind of temporary outage, permanent change of URIs, or some upgrade somewhere which causes the issue?

Comment: I can confirm this with my own account. To highlight: **entering https://me.yahoo.com/ manually works**.

Comment: No changes on our end that I'm aware of. Must be something Yahoo's doing. Here's hoping this fixes itself or else we're gonna have a neat little problem on our hands...

Comment: me.yahoo.com also worked for me, maybe the default openid endpoint for yahoo should be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed the default Yahoo! openId endpoint to `https://me.yahoo.com`, which fixes this issue.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.9.22.1881, meta rev 2014.9.22.2591).

Comment: Sorry, not fixed. Still getting errors.

Comment: @bart - can you be more specific? I can login no problem using Yahoo (just clicking the button and logging in to Yahoo). What are you seeing? What are the errors?