# "No OpenID endpoint found" when trying to login using Yahoo! in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, ios-app, yahoo-openid

I was given an iPhone 6s with iOS 9.3 and I re-installed Stack Exchange app. I had always been able to login with the old iphone but now I can't use the app because when I perform:

Log in --> Login with another OpenID --> Login using Yahoo!

then I get this error message:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider. No OpenID endpoint found

But it seems that Yahoo! works fine if I try to login to Stack Overflow on my web browser. So, why is the app not working anymore? Shall I change some settings?

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next website build.

In the mean time, you can choose the last option to manually enter an openId and use "me.yahoo.com". Based on 
[Is Yahoo OpenID login broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239635/is-yahoo-openid-login-broken), this may or may not have been broken for the last 18 months.